# Login: password hash vs successful decrypt

Tags: encryption, authentication, hash

Using a one- way function (e.g. BCrypt) for password handling in password based login is a common approach.

When an application uses a key derived from user’s password for encrypting a private key, is it secure to rely on successful decryption on login?

**Example:**

- Registration (all steps performed client- side):

  1. Derive a key (A) from user’s password (e.g. using PBKDF2 with 100k iterations).
  2. Use key A to encrypt user’s private key (using authenticated encryption; e.g. AES in GCM mode).
  3. Store required information in user’s database record (e.g. ciphertext, salt, …).
- Login (all steps performed on client- side):

  1. Load user's database record by username.
  2. Derive key (B) from user’s password (using same method used on registration).
  3. Try to decrypt users private key using key B.

Comment: A and B are actually the same thing, right? you derived them using the same method from the same password.

Comment: One of the biggest weaknesses would be brute forcing of passwords, which if successful would give you the user's private key

Comment: @NH In case the valid/correct password was entered: yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a workable approach, *when* you use authenticated encryption, as you've indicated.  The authentication tag on the encrypted data is analogous to a stored password hash, and GCM is specifically designed to prevent message forgery (i.e., a valid tag constructed without access to the private key).

In fact, GMAC is a variant of GCM mode that is designed not to encrypt data, but *just* to provide a signature with a shared key over some data.

It's important to note that this should not be done with non-authenticated ciphers, as even with padding being used to detect "correct" decryption, this would lead to a (slightly better than) 1/256 chance of any password working correctly by having correct padding despite being the incorrect key.

All this being said, I don't think this is a *good* idea, because it's much easier to have implementation errors in this than it is in a standard password storage scheme.  Attacking this scheme is equally easy/difficult to attacking a separate PBKDF2 hash for the user password, which is a well studied authentication mechanism.  If you're worried about CPU time with computing two PBKDF2 hashes, you can do the following:

1. Compute `key = PBKDF2(Password, Salt, N)` to derive the symmetric key.
2. Compute `pwhash = PBKDF2(Password, Salt, N+1)` to derive the stored password hash.  (This can be done with only a single extra round on the original hash above.)

Inverting `PBKDF2(Password, Salt, N+1)` into `PBKDF2(Password, Salt, N)` is equivalent to inverting `HMAC` on whatever hash function you use.

The scheme above is the scheme used by Lastpass for authentication vs decrypting your password vault.  (Only `pwhash` is sent to their server so they cannot recover the key for the password vault from that.)

Comment: In this case, I would also recommend knocking a few bytes off the output; for instance, only use the first 48 of the native 64 bytes of PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512, so that output of PBKDF2(x,y,N) is by definition insufficient for use in calculating PBKDF2(x,y,N+1).  Personally, I'd say run two different salts instead, but as you said, if the CPU time was a very serious concern...